# xquery- how to put a 'range' condition on some nodes' immediately previous and next sibling nodes

Tags: xquery

Kindly take a look at the sample below--

```
<div class="patent_bibdata">
     <b> First list</b>
     <a href="1"> Name #1</a>
     <a href="2"> Name #2</a>
     <b> Second list</b>
     <a href="1"> Name #2_1</a>
     <a href="2"> Name #2_2</a>
</div>
```

Now, I want to extract the links after the 'b' element that has text "First List"-- however, I dont want the links after the 'b' element that has text "Second list"-- and the number of links after "First List" is not known to me.

What I thought of, is something like this--

```
....XQuery code defining the document as variable named "doc"
let $list:= $doc/div[ @class="patent_bibdata"]/b[. = 'First list']/following-sibling::text() -- but this should get everything after 'First list'-- including 'Second List' and 'Name #2_1' and 'Name #2_2'
```

Now, only the text in the 2 'b' tags-- (i.e. 'Name #1' and 'Name #2' in our example) are known to me-- so I think I have to somehow put conditions and retrieve the links (that I need), putting conditions on the immediate-predecessor-sibling and immediate-successor-sibling of those links--- what are the commands to put those conditions(if I am right so far)? And if I am not right, then how do I go about getting that set of links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
$doc/div[ @class="patent_bibdata"]/b[. = ' First list']/following-sibling::a[not(preceding-sibling::b[. = ' Second list'])]
```

Considering the amount of rather basic questions you asked today about XQuery it might be advisable to get a fundamental understanding about XQuery first. There are some very good books out there, I especially like the one from Priscilla Walmsley.

Comment: @dirkk-- following-sibling:: All siblings of the context node that follow it....preceding-sibling:: All the siblings of the context node that precede it... then in the code you have given above, wont the following-siblings of 'First List' be the same as the preceding siblings of 'Second List'? i am a bit confused here...

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you want to extract the both a tags `<a href="1"> Name #1</a><a href="2"> Name #2</a>`. therefore you look for all a-nodes following your first b-node, which do not have the second b-node as a as preceding sibling (the [] is a predicate syntax in XQuery).
Also, even if you don't immediately understand the code please at least try to run it yourself and try to figure out what it does. This can be easily done in this case by simply removing some predicates and looking at the output.